# Registry pattern in PHP for create class

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have a pattern to create class and hold in array to return existing instanced class in future use.

```
abstract class Models extends Factory {
    public static function getPlaces($dbConfigName = "my") {
        return parent::getClass($dbConfigName, 'Places');
    }
    public static function getCategories($dbConfigName = "mo") {
        return parent::getClass($dbConfigName, 'Categories');
    }
}
```

And another:

```
abstract class Factory {
    protected static $classes = [];
    protected static function getClass($dbConfigName, $model) {
        $config = Config::getConfiguration($dbConfigName);
        $namespace = "App\\Models\\{$config['driver']}\\{$model}";
        $key = $dbConfigName.$namespace;
        if (!array_key_exists($key, self::$classes)) {
            echo "<p>New: $namespace</p>";
            self::$classes[$key] = new $namespace($config);
            $test = static::$classes[$key];
            echo'<pre>';print_r(new \ReflectionClass($test));echo '</pre>';
        }
        return self::$classes[$key];
    }
}
```

The class created with the name of Catogires successfull in first call this function:

```
$categories = Models::getCategories();
```

and inside of this categories class i want to create another class to use:

```
$categoryFields = Models::getPlaces();
```

Bu the above code inside of Categories class create again Categories instead of Places class. In my test with reflection and print the namespace before create class is this:

```
***** This is for create Categories class for first time*****
New: App\Models\MySQL\Categories

ReflectionClass Object
(
    [name] => App\Models\MySQL\Categories
)

***** This is for create Places class inside of categories class *****
New: App\Models\MySQL\Places

ReflectionClass Object
(
    [name] => App\Models\MySQL\Categories
)
```

I push my code to git with test code. just for running enter your database setting in Config.php file. Don't need to setting up MongoDB, the default test code for debugging just available for MySQL.
[Source on the Github](https://github.com/jafaripur/multiple-database-pattern)

Comment: have you tried to debug inside the method `Factory::getClass` to see how the variables are built?

Comment: Yes, I debug it. I added latest debug information in end of the post, with instancing the "App\Models\MySQL\Places" the class the created class is "App\Models\MySQL\Categories"

Comment: yes, but as the class name is build from a string, it could be useful to follow how the string is passed around and to check if the values are correct

Comment: Have you tried replacing all instances of `self::` with `static::`? [Late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Comment: @Jimbo Yes, i changed and again doesn't work!

Comment: Just debug entire "getPlaces" method, you must be certain $config is what you expect it to be. And that "new" is returning exactly expected object. Also maybe somehow in your "self::$classes[$key]" another object is lying.

Comment: @Clickbeetle I checked it and every thing is OK, The last code section is my test result.

Comment: @ArazJafaripur It can not be ok, because in result you have another object and it must be seen in debugger at this line of code "return self::$classes[$key];"

Comment: @Clickbeetle I added my test code and reflection of created class. the last code the result of this test for printing the namespace should instanced and created object name with reflection. Check getClass() in Factory class.

Comment: @ArazJafaripur can you replace this: `self::$classes[$key] = new $namespace($config); $test = static::$classes[$key];` With this: `$a = new $namespace($config); var_dump($a);` And post result, when you invoke "Models::getPlaces();"

Comment: @Clickbeetle This is create Fields object. but why the created object and saved in array in next request return the Categories Object?

Comment: @ArazJafaripur Can not tell you without the rest of code. What we see, that it actually works, returns the appropriate instance. I think a problem lies in saving instance for future use. Maybe "$key" is not unique or it is overwritten by Categories object, i don't know. Need more code.

Comment: @Clickbeetle The array key is unique, it's merged with db config and namespace. this is so strange issue!

Comment: @ArazJafaripur I pasted your code in my IDE and test it myself. The part you showed us, working as expected. So you have your error outside of the code you provided. You definitely has some inherited classes from this abstract class, so maybe problem is there.

Comment: @Clickbeetle Check the latest edit, I upload codes to github.

Comment: @ArazJafaripur Ok, so.. Your instance changes from test to user in MySQLOwnClient on 37 line, during calling to pdo constructor. After this call, "$this" magically changes to User instance. You can comment out line 37 and line 38 and run your test, and you will see everything is fine. Your test will also work correctly if in MySQLOwnClient you won't override pdo constructor. So I don't recommend extending \PDO directly, you can wrap it inside your class.